# How to check for duplicated inside this JSON Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need a way to check if a Server already exist inside my JSON Array.

Here is an example JSON Array:

```
[{
  "ID": 14,
  "PID": 15728,
  "Online": 1,
  "Servers": "staging,dev,test"
}, {
  "ID": 9,
  "PID": 6048,
  "Online": 1,
  "Servers": ""
}, {
  "ID": 8,
  "PID": 13060,
  "Online": 1,
  "Servers": "ubuntu,test"
}, {
  "ID": 7,
  "PID": 15440,
  "Online": 1,
  "Servers": "main"
}]
```

I need a JavaScript function to handle this.

Example calls could be:

```
checkForDupes("staging") -> true
checkForDupes("debian") -> false
checkForDupes("ubuntu") -> true
checkForDupes("test") -> true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `some()` and `includes()` methods or arrays and `split()` method of string:

```js
let data = [
    {"ID": 14, "PID": 15728, "Online": 1, "Servers": "staging,dev,test"},
    {"ID": 9, "PID": 6048, "Online": 1, "Servers": ""},
    {"ID": 8, "PID": 13060, "Online": 1, "Servers": "ubuntu,test"},
    {"ID": 7, "PID": 15440, "Online": 1, "Servers": "main"}
];

function checkForDupes(d, s) {
  return d.some(o => o["Servers"].split(",").includes(s));
}

console.log(checkForDupes(data, "staging"));
console.log(checkForDupes(data, "debian"));
console.log(checkForDupes(data, "ubuntu"));
console.log(checkForDupes(data, "test"));
```

**Description:**

- `.some()` will run the test function against each object and return true if
  any one object passes the test.
- `.split()` will create an array from string of "Servers" property delimited by `,`
- `.includes()` will check where the passed name exists in array or not returning true or false as appropriate.

**Useful Resources:**

- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: do you mind explaining how each of the methods is helping to acheive the result

Comment: from the moment of my comment the two solutions working great! so thank you Mohammad Usman and PSK. I accepted the first one as it was posted earlier and because the code is extremely compact!

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkdupe = function(param) {
    var count = [];
    for(i=0;i<json.length;i++)
        {
            if(json[i].Servers.split(',').indexOf(param) != -1)
                {
                    count.push(json[i].ID);
                }
        }
    if(count.length>1){
        return true;
    }
}
```

you can use that count array to get more detail

**indexOf** might be the best choice rather than contains or includes, if it comes to a point where speed matters